# how to add foreign key data to the primary key data and display it

Tags: php, mysql

**connection**

```
<?php

$host = "localhost";
$user = "root";
$password = "";

mysql_connect($host, $user, $password);
mysql_select_db("admin");
SESSION_START();
if($_SESSION["loggedin"]!="true")
    header("location:login.php");

$id = $_REQUEST["Emp_ID"];
$test = mysql_query("select * from Employee inner join department where Emp_ID =$id");
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($test);
?>
```

**table for the details**

```
<table align="left" border="0" width="700px" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="5px">
        <tr>
            <th>Name :</th>
            <td><?php echo $row["Emp_Fname"];?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Handphone :</th>
            <td><?php echo $row["ContactNo_HP"];?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Telephone :</th>
            <td><?php echo $row["ContactNo_Home"];?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Address :</th>
            <td><?php echo $row["Emp_Address"];?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Email :</th>
            <td><?php echo $row["Emp_Email"];?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Department :</th>
            <td><?php echo $row["Dept_Desp"];?></td>  
        </tr>
    </table>
```

1. My Dept_Desp is a data inside the table 'department'
2. Display the first data of department name only, can't display the true one

Comment: So I guess I don't understand what the question/problem actually is. Of course, you may want to actually specify the join condition for your tables in the SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select * from Employee left join department on employee.department_id = department.department_id where Emp_ID =$id
```

Something like this...also read up on mysqli or pdo....your db method is horribly insecure.